# Unable to get the alert text using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I have the below code to verify the alert text and then dismiss. Verifying the alert text is failing.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alertText = alert.getText();
```

alertText is returned as null. So the next step to assert the text is failing. 
Next step:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Accepts the alert without any issue.

Another weird scenario is when I debug in eclipse its working fine. But when I am running assertion throws error.

Another differecnce I found while running and debugging.
During running the alert come with this message **don't let this page create more messages**

Looks very weird.

Comment: I tried this but it dint help.

Comment: What is thext present on alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing message as "don't let this page create more messages" is browser feature there to prevent sites from showing hundreds of alerts.

As while debugging your code it is working, it should work even while running too. If not working, definitely its sync issue. I hope adding some hardwait definitely help.

Other approach to get alert text from alert popup:

```
public String getJsAlertText()
{
Object txt = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return
window.alert.myAlertText;");
return (String)txt;
}
```

Comment: Showing message as "don't let this page create more messages" is browser feature there to prevent sites from showing hundreds of alerts.// Yes. But why is it comming only while running. While debugging I am not observing this.

Comment: As per my knowledge while debugging we will wait for some time to perform any action, I mean to say as long as you say proceed step execution won't happen. However while running its continuous actions happening in seconds, so browser thinks its as some JS code issue and try to freeze the browser by calling alert in an infinite loop.

Comment: Object txt = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return
window.alert.myAlertText;");
This is throwing exception. Modal dialog present. How can we achieve this?